# Best method to display tpl?

Tags: php, smarty

I coded this for banner rotation. I wonder how can I add it to `tpl` file to show it there?

```
<?php

  $fcontents = join ('', file ('banner_ads.txt'));
  $s_con = split("~",$fcontents);

  $banner_no = rand(0,(count($s_con)-1));
  echo $s_con[$banner_no];

?>
```

Comment: Please tell us what you mean by a tpl. Do you use Smarty?

Comment: yes, I want to add this to my tpl file

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First of all, your page should include the Smarty templating engine. In the PHP file, you should place your logic. In this file, you fetch the banner. Then, you can assign it to your template.

Your code will be something like this:

```
include('Smarty.class.php');
$smarty = new Smarty;

$fcontents = join ('', file ('banner_ads.txt'));
$s_con = split("~",$fcontents);
$banner_no = rand(0,(count($s_con)-1));
$smarty->assign('banner', $s_con[$banner_no]);

$smarty->display('index.tpl');
```

Now, in your template, just place the banner like this:

```
{$banner}
```